# MongoDB/Mongoose - Update a number in document by performing Addition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB collection where I store time & costs saved. **When the users enter the data for the first time** the document kinda looks like this:

```
{ "fullName" : "john smith",
  "company" : "xyz",
  "email" : "john.smith@xyz.com",
  "timeSaved" : 50 //this is in minutes
  "moneySaved" : 10 //this is in dollars
}
```

Now when the user enters the data again I find if a document already exists for this user and if it does I get it.

This time the user entered:

1. Time Saved 55
2. money Saved 10

I want to **add** the new values to the existing values. So after the documents shows this:

```
"timeSaved" : 105 // old 50 + new 55
"moneySaved" : 20 // old 10 + new 10
```

Whats the best way to achieve this. Is there an inbuilt function in mongodb/mongoose that can help with this.

Comment: [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) will help.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator. The `$inc` operator increments a field by a specified value

For example in your case:

```
UserModel.update(
    SomeFindCriteria,
   { $inc: { timeSaved: newTimeSaved, moneySaved: newMoneySaved } }
)
```

Comment: ah perfect! so simple! Thank you for the help. :D I'll accept the answer once I have tested it out.